# Paying French parking ticket from abroad

Tags: france, car-rentals

I got a parking ticket for apparently parking my rental car in the wrong place in front of my hotel. But as I had to leave quickly to get my flight back home, I was unable to pay it in France.

I figure that I should have bought a stamp in a French shop and thrown the ticket into a postbox. But how should I do that from abroad? Is there a way to pay it online?

**Edit:** I don't have a "fancy" ticket that could be paid online

Comment: Not sure about it, but try to contact a french consulate.

Comment: one thing worth noting, French fines increase with time. So if you pay it, don't wait for too long

Comment: just to make it clear: I am in germany; and I don't have ticket that can be payed for online.

Comment: can't you send post from Germany to France?

Answer (score 3):

The French system has a weak point when it goes to collecting fines past the borders, at least for traffic offenses. Even speeding tickets do not follow through when foreigners get back to their home countries, unless arrested by police directly. At least for now, since the government is in the process of partnering with other EU countries to be able to claim speeding fines to foreign drivers. I don't know if parking violations are concerned, as they are relatively small fish.

The aformentioned advice is not here to say it's okay to break driving laws, anyway.

It is the rental agency that you should rather deal with. Once they get the ticket registered with your car, they can forward the fine to your credit card with additional processing fees. Therefore, I would advise you to call them, tell them about the ticket and ask them what to do next.

Comment: are you sure they're still in the process? Theoretically, other EU residents should already receive the fine in their home country (maybe since beginning of 2012). Maybe some source is needed to confirm this.

Comment: Here is a press release regarding the EU Directive concerning the sharing of registration data across EU borders. It also lists the offences covered by the directive: speeding, driving under the influence of alcohol or drugs, non-use of a seat belt and failing to stop at a red light.  EU countries (excluding UK, Ireland and Denmark) have two years to implement the Directive intheir national laws.     http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cms_data/docs/pressdata/en/trans/124809.pdf

Comment: This is not specific to France but it is changing.

Comment: If I recall correctly, France has already an agreement with Belgium (and probably other countries) to exchange information about fines. Nonetheless, think about impact if you later wish to apply for a Visa,... A small fine probably won't make that much of a difference, but it is always better to leave a country in peace, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Two years ago I got a parking ticket while I was in France. The car was mine, not rented.
When I came back home (in Italy), I simply put the ticket receipt and a check for the owed amount in an envelope and I sent it to the address I found on the ticket itself.
I have not heard anything more about the ticket, so I suppose the French police cashed the check and everything went ok.

Answer (score 3):

Received a parking violation May 2015 in France via a notice on the windshield of our rental vehicle. Had parked, as all others did, partially on sidewalk and partially on road. No signs to indicate no parking.
Tried to go to municipal police stn and also mayor's office to try to pay as the ticket only indicated an infraction, but not the fine. Finally the tourist info office let us know that there was nothing we could do, just wait for the fine.
We informed the rental company on return of the vehicle, but they said it could only be dealt with by their head office. 
Rental company charged 20 Euros for getting a fine and we just received a 35 Euro charge from Centre d'Encaissment des Amendes France, in the mail, with options for payment, including online. There is also opportunity to contest the ticket, but only via post. The  online payment was straightforward and easy, with instructions available in English. 
Costly error!